# JavaScript blur function in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem with my blur event. It triggers many times instead of 1.

Here is the code:

```js
function EditMode() {
  if (!edit) {

    $('.editable').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    HtmlEdit();
    edit = 1;
    $('.mybutton').css({
      "background": "#007acc",
      "color": "#fff"
    });
    $('.mybutton').html('Сохранить');
    $('.mybutton').css("border", "1px solid #007acc");
    $('.web-table').css("border", "2px solid #007acc");

  } else {
    $('.editable').unbind('click');
    edit = 0;
    $('.mybutton').css({
      "background": "#fff",
      "color": "#000"
    });
    $('.web-table').css("border", "1px solid #d1d1d1");
    $('.mybutton').html('Изменить');
    $('.mybutton').css("border", "1px solid #d1d1d1");
    $('.editable').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
  }
}

function HtmlEdit() {
  $('.editable').click(function() {

    $(this).keydown(function() {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;

      }
    })

    $(this).keyup(function() {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.editable').blur();

      }
    })

    $(this).find('.editable').blur(function() {
      alert('it works');
    })
  })
}
```

The 1st function is triggered by a button click and makes the `td` who has the `.editable` class - editable with HTML5.
The 2nd function should disable the `br` (next row in text editcontent mode)" when you press enter and should save the changes to DB. Also the changes should be saved when the `td` looses it focus. So I decided to use the `blur` function.

But this code does not get the alert.

And when I'm writing this way:

```
$(this).blur(function() { alert('it works');
```

I get a loop of alerts: The 1st time one alert, 2nd time 2 alerts, 3d - 3, and sometimes 2 or 3 without any logic. Can you help me? I need only one run of the blur function.

The HTML code:

```
<table class="web-table" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 122, 204);">
<tbody>
<tr><th id="off_col_num">№</th><th id="off_col_id">offer ID</th><th id="off_col_name">Название</th><th id="off_col_geo">Geo</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td class="editable" contenteditable="true">1234</td><td class="editable" contenteditable="true">test fdg dfg</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td class="editable" contenteditable="true">1296</td><td class="editable" contenteditable="true">Кожаные кроссовки Ecco</td><td>1</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/az4koq96/

Comment: We'd like it if you could provide a full [mcve]; which means the HTML on which this code applied, and the least amount of overall code which still shows the error.

Comment: I added the HTML

Comment: where do you call the `EditMode()` function?

Comment: on a button click -$('#edit-button').click(EditMode);

Comment: Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/az4koq96/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get multiple alerts because every time you click inside an editable field, an additional blur() handler is registered to it.

After 2 clicks inside the field, you have 2 handler which are called on blur.

After 3 click 3 ...

The same with the keydown and keyup events. You only need to register the handlers once.

```
$(".editable").keydown(...);
$(".editable").keyup(function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
$(".editable").blur(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because when you call the `.blur()` function you are calling it for all of the cells in the table. Here's your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/az4koq96/1/

The changes I made were in the `HtmlEdit()` function. I changed `$('.editable').blur()` to `$(this).blur()` and moved the binding of the blur function outside of the click function

```
var edit = 0;
$('#offer-edit-button').click(EditMode);

function EditMode()
{
  if (!edit) {
   //TableEdit(); 
   $('.editable').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
   HtmlEdit(); edit=1;
   $('.mybutton').css({"background": "#007acc", "color": "#fff"});
   $('.mybutton').html('Save');
   $('.mybutton').css("border", "1px solid #007acc");
   $('.web-table').css("border", "2px solid #007acc");

  }
  else {
   $('.editable').unbind('click'); edit = 0 ;
   $('.mybutton').css({"background": "#fff", "color": "#000"});
   $('.web-table').css("border", "1px solid #d1d1d1");
   $('.mybutton').html('Edit');
   $('.mybutton').css("border", "1px solid #d1d1d1");
   $('.editable').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
  }
}

function HtmlEdit()
{
  $('.editable').click(function ()
  {

    $(this).keydown(function(){
            if(event.keyCode==13)
            {
             return false;

            }
    })  

    $(this).keyup(function(){
            if(event.keyCode==13)
            {
             $(this).blur();

            }
    })  


    $(this).off('blur');
    $(this).blur(function() { alert('it works here'); 

    var data = [];
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"data": data},        
    url: "inc/save-offer.php",
    success: function (anwser)
    {
      $('#aw-wrapper').html(anwser);

    }

    });


    })


  })
}
```

Comment: @mrdeath4 can you please provide the HTML and preferably a jsfiddle for us to work with

Comment: @mrdeath4 I updated my answer and provided a fiddle for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149822/discussion-between-cumminup07-and-mrdeath4).

Comment: Your fiddle doesnot work . it makes many alerts when yuo type enter or your cursor is on TABLE

Comment: @mrdeath Try the one in my answer again,  it is working for me,  I can no longer reproduce your error

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! My mistake was in   $(this).blur(function);You should off the click handler not the blur, and run the HtmlEdit again in the end of blur function

Comment: No it doesntot work again. It worked for one time. and IF u make the edit 2nd time i get 1000 alerts